# ESP32 with SIM800L

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, sim800, sim800l

Do you have a code for auto-answering a call using ESP32 and SIM800L? What I want is, I will call the number that is inserted in the SIM800L and I am expecting it to answer automatically. I am trying to make a code but I can't get it. I am expecting to get an accurate code for my concern.

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim800l(7, 8); // RX, TX

void setup() { 
   Serial.begin(9600); 
   sim800l.begin(9600); 
   delay(1000); // Set auto answer mode to 1 ring 
   sim800l.println("AT+ATS0=1"); 
} 

void loop() { 
    if (sim800l.available()) { 
        Serial.write(sim800l.read()); 
    } 
    if (Serial.available()) { 
        sim800l.write(Serial.read()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code of what you have tried? That may help people to answer your question.

Comment: #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim800l(7, 8); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sim800l.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  // Set auto answer mode to 1 ring
  sim800l.println("AT+ATS0=1");
}

void loop() {
  if (sim800l.available()) {
    Serial.write(sim800l.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    sim800l.write(Serial.read());
  }
}